# SQL Data Manipulation (Adding FK and Displaying one Data from different table)

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL and we have an activity. I only have two problems in my query, first is adding the FK because when I run it, this will have an error that show like this: near "FOREIGN": syntax error and I don't know why.
Second is I dont know how to display the Products, Vendor ID and Name that comes from different table (This is the part of the instruction:
Determine which products have a quantity of less than 1000 then display the products Vendor ID and Name)

```
      CREATE TABLE Products (ProductID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Description varchar (100), Quantity 
      int, Price int (50), VendorID int NOT NULL);
      CREATE TABLE Vendors (VendorID int  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar (50), ContactNum int);
      ALTER TABLE Products ADD FOREIGN KEY (VendorID) REFERENCES Vendors (VendorID); 

      INSERT INTO Vendors VALUES ('V00001', 'Universal Corporation','8633-76131');
      INSERT INTO Vendors VALUES('V00002', 'Liwayway Corporation','8844-8441');
      INSERT INTO Vendors VALUES ('V00003', 'Monde Nissin', '7759-5000');
      Select * FROM Vendors;

      INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('P000101', 'Jack N Jill Piattos', 1000, 15, 'V00001');
      INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('P000102', 'Jack N Jill Nova', 1000, 15, 'V00001');
      INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('P000105', 'Oishi Prawn Crackers', 700, 8, 'V00002');
      INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('P000107', 'Nissin Eggnog Cookies', 850, 7, 'V00003');
      SELECT * FROM Products;


      UPDATE Products SET Quantity = Quantity + 274 WHERE ProductID = 'P000101';
      UPDATE Products SET Quantity = Quantity - 42 WHERE ProductID = 'P000107';
      SELECT * FROM Products;

      SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, Description, Quantity FROM Products WHERE Quantity < 1000;
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? They are completely different products.

Comment: Also, adding a FK does not create a column in the table. The column (VendorID in your case) needs to exist before you can create an FK against it